# How do I close the Android keyboard programmatically when user has selected an option in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

[Android OS: Activty UI]

How do I close the Android keyboard programmatically when user has selected an option in AutoCompleteTextView ?

I have already tries these things but none of them worked:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow (autoCompleteTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);
imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(autoCompleteTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Good Luck